# Find the completion of the metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, function-spaces

Metric spaces are:

a) Let $X = C[0,1]$ and $$d(x,y) = \sup_{0\le t \le1} t \vert x(t) - y(t)\vert$$

b) Let $$X = \{x \in C[0,1]: \sup_{0\le t \le1}t^{-2}\vert x(t)\vert < \infty\}, d(x,y) = \sup_{0\le t \le1}  \vert x(t) - y(t)\vert$$

I thought that completion of the first one will have the functions that diverge at $t = 0$ with some restriction, and the second one will be the set of functions that are $0$ at $t = 0$. I could not find a way to solve it properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for b): The completion is  $\{x\in C[0,1]: x(0)=0\}$ with the sup norm. If $x \in C[0,1]$ with $x(0)=0$  define $x_n(t)=0$ for $0\leq t \leq \frac 1 n$, $x_n(t)=x(t)$ for $\frac 2 n \leq t \leq 1$ and let $x_n$ have  a straight line graph in $[\frac 1 n, \frac  2 n]$. Then $x_n \in X$ and $x_n \to x$ in sup norm.

The completion for $X$ in part a) is $\{x \in C(0,1]: tx(t)  \, \text {is bounded}\}$. [Notice that I have $C(0,1]$ instead of $C[0,1]$]. I will let you supply a proof using an idea similar to the one for part b).

Comment: I believe with your explanation the completion of part b) is $\{x \in C[0,1] : x(0): 0\}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Roxose You are very right. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: As you suggested, for part a) $x: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ where x is continuous on $(0,1]$, $\lim_{t \to 0^+} t x(t) < \infty$ and $x(0) = c, c \in \Bbb{R}$ then let $x_n(t) = n(x(1/n) - c)t +c$ for $0 \le t \le 1/n$, $x_n(t) = x(t)$ for $1/n \le t \le 1$ then $x_n \in X$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ in sup norm. I find saying that $x \in C(0,1]$ a little problematic since x also needs to be defined at $t = 0$.

Comment: Additionally, by this kind of reasoning, we are showing that there are sequences in X that converges to the functions in the sets we specified. I believe we need to show that the space we proposed is complete. I cannot imagine a way to show it is indeed a complete space. Can you help me here?

Comment: An example of a function in then completion is $\ln t$. It is not necessary to define the functions in the completion at $0$.  @Roxose